# What does it mean by propagating all exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions, unchecked-exception

I was told to propagate all exceptions. This sentence means active propagation such like :

public void doSomething() throws SomeException{

```
try{

    doSomethingThatCanThrowException();

} catch (SomeException e){

   e.addContextInformation(�more info�);
   throw e;  //throw e, or wrap it � see next line.

   //throw new WrappingException(e, �more information�);

}
```

or passive propagation :

public void doSomething() throws SomeException {

```
try{

    doSomethingThatCanThrowException();

} finally {
   //clean up � close open resources etc.
}
```

}

.Also what does propagating all exception mean ?

Cheers

Comment: It means don't catch it, but throw it.

Comment: So propogating exception mean only to catch it. I should avoid catching it

Comment: Catching an exception is a promise: "Whatever caused this exception, my method can fulfill its job even in this exceptional case, so my caller need not be informed about the problem." That's a tough promise, so you better let exceptions propagate to your caller. And if you don't have resources that really need closing, you can go completely without `try/catch/finally`, just declaring a `throws` clause for your method.